# express res.redirect target page js not loaded

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using Node.js + Express + Jade to demo some very simple pages. I got this problem for two days. I googled a lot, but cannot find answer. Basically, I redirect from a page to another. And on the target page, I have some socket.io code inside document.ready. The problem is from /pageone, the pagetwo is rendered correctly(but url in browser is still /pageone), but the code inside document.ready is not executed.

My router.js

```
app.post('/pageone', session, function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/pagetwo');
});

app.get('/pagetwo', function(req, res){
    res.render('pagetwo', { title: 'demo' });
});
```

My pagetwo jade

```
doctype
html
head
    title #{title} - My Site
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js')
    script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        });
body
    h1 DEMO
```

The result is that I can see DEMO on the page but alert box is not showing. But if I directly visit /pagetwo, the alert box is showing.

Many thanks

////// EDITED //////
This is my app.js

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, session = require('express-session');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', port);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(session({ secret: 'gdfgsdrgesrgerge', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

require('./controller/router')(app);
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
})
```

And this is my router.js

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/pageone', function(req, res){
    res.render('pageone', { title: 'Welcome' });
});

app.post('/pageone', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/pagetwo');
});

app.get('/pagetwo', function(req, res){
    res.render('pagetwo', { title: 'demo' });
});
};
```

Comment: What is the `session` middleware you are using for the `/pageone` route?

Comment: ^Was just about to ask this. Also, do you see any errors showing up in the browser console?

Comment: I use express-session

Comment: How are you initializing `express-session`? Is the browser hanging on `/pageone`?

Comment: @Nindaff I initialize it use `var session = require('express-session'); app.use(session({secret: 'jfeoifjei', cookie: {maxAge: 60000}}))`. And yes the browser hanging on `/pageone`

Comment: could you post all of your code for `router.js`? I think i know whats going on.

Comment: My apology, there is no session parameter in the app.post('/pageone'...). code added